# How to list all packages marked as 'group'

Tags: fedora, package-management, dependencies, dnf

The `dnf` command is able to mark packages as `install`, `remove` or `group` [1]. To list all packages marked as `install`, the command `dnf repoquery --userinstalled` [2] can be used.

**My question is:** Is there a command to query all packages marked as `group`?

1. https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mark-command-label
2. https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#repoquery-command-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 4.2.11 (released on Sep 19, 2019) the `dnf repoquery` command supports the `%{reason}` tag in the query format string.  This outputs one of `user`, `group`, `dependency`, `weak-dependency`, `unknown`, or `(none)`.

To list all packages installed as part of a group:

```
dnf repoquery --installed --qf='%{name}-%{evr}.%{arch} (%{reason})' | grep '(group)$'
```